# Vertical space in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to add configurable vertical space to GNU Emacs `org-mode`?

The customary arrangement of todo items is something like

```
* STARTED Feature 1.
** DONE Subfeature 1.1.
** TODO Subfeature 1.2.
* TODO Feature 2.
** TODO Subfeature 2.1.
```

If the number of high-level items is high enough, it becomes difficult to havigate, and adding newlines before `Feature 2` will attach the space to `Subfeature 1.2`, and it will be collapsed along with it.

What I want is for the items to be treated the same as the file above, but **look** like this:

```
* STARTED Feature 1.
** DONE Subfeature 1.1.
** TODO Subfeature 1.2.

* TODO Feature 2.
** TODO Subfeature 2.1.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to consider asking questions like this on http://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but have you tried customizing the height (move cursor to top-level heading and `M-x customize-face`), or setting `org-odd-levels-only`?

Comment: Here is something that I use when I hit the custom reorganize/sort function:  `(let ((query-replace-lazy-highlight nil)) (replace-regexp "\n+\\*\\* " "\n\n** " nil (point-min) (point-max)) (replace-regexp "\n+\\* " "\n\n\n* " nil (point-min) (point-max)))`